# NSIS File /x ... unexplainable error?

Tags: installation, nsis

Im trying to copy the contents of a subdirectory, excluding asubdirectory in this subdirectory. However, the /x option gives an error, which I cannot explain. Here my nsis scrpit line :

```
File /r "..\myDir" /x "..\myDir\.svn"
```

If I omit the /x part, the script line is accepted and compiled without problems. With the /x option I get an error that there is an error ... and no more information.

Whats wrong with the above script line?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters are in the wrong order, the include filespec is always the last parameter.
The /x switch is not documented to take anything other than file/directory names, the best you can do is: `File /r /x .svn "..\myDir"`

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly the order. Maybe the nsis documentation about this should spent one line more also.